# Why doesn't an unassigned Vue instance get garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, garbage-collection

Here's the standard way to use VueJS on the HTML page (without bundles). No assignment.

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello'
  }
});
</script>
```

Why Garbage Collector doesn't collect this Vue object?

Comment: Because something like [keep-alive](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/components/keep-alive.js) exists.

Comment: How do you know that GC doesn't collect the un-assigned Vue instance object? This comment in relation to Vue Router indicates how Router gets collected when used without assignment (it's a general functionality of GC to collect such unassigned instances, however GC implementations may vary across different browsers): https://stackoverflow.com/a/30319602/2442714

Comment: What makes you think that it is not garbage-collected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you instantiate a Vue object, it actually mounts itself to the DOM element, here `#root` element, as briefly hinted in this documentation page [The Vue Instance > Instance Lifecycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

By using Developer Tools in your browser, like in Chrome, you can open the console tab and prompt, type  `console.log(window.$vm0);` and hit enter.  And you get access to your Vue runtime instance even it was not assigned to a variable:

```
> Vue {_uid: 2, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: Vue, …}
```

I've opened another question on [how to properly access the Vue instance if it wasn't assigned to a variable during instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59479496/accessing-vue-instance-from-global-scope-if-instance-was-not-assigned-to-a-varia).

**The main point, as an answer to this current question, is that there is actually variable assignment / DOM mounting happening behind the scenes by Vue itself, so that is why garbage collection is not triggering.**

*PS. There is a detailed documentation article [Avoiding Memory Leaks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) in relation to handling Garbage Collection in a Vue application.*

Comment: I guess [this one is more relevant](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/d9b27a92bd5277ee23a4e68a8bd31ecc72f4c99b/src/core/instance/lifecycle.js#L80) for accessing the instance. I couldn't find where `$vm0` is assigned though

Answer (score 2):

A Vue application consists of a Vue instance created with new Vue and mounted in DOM element with id '#root'. Vue is running all this magic behind the scene that's why garbage collector will not collect Vue object.

In addition to data properties, Vue instances expose a number of instance properties and methods. These are prefixed with $ to differentiate them from user-defined properties. For example:

```
var data = { title: 'Hello' }
var vm = new Vue({ 
    el: '#root',
    data: data
});
// If you check below code
vm.$data === data // => true
vm.$el === document.getElementById('root') // => true
```