# Accessing Vue instance from global scope if instance was not assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to access the Vue instance from a global scope like `window` or `document` or by `document.getElementById("app")`, if Vue was instantiated without assigning it's constructor's return value to a variable?

In example:

```js
// Instead of:
// var vm = new Vue({
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted: function () {
    console.log('this scope:', this);
  }
});
```

Comment: Only if you did something like `window.app = this;` inside I guess.

Comment: There might be, but why do you care? Assigning the instance to a variable definitely is the proper solution.

Comment: Why do we care? There are several use cases, if not for pure curiosity. Like running script to discern whether the web page the script is loaded in has a mounted Vue instance. (Hint: there actually is a way but I'll let you figure it out...it seems they have not mentioned it in the official docs or I was not able to find it there).

Comment: Btw there are many examples in the docs of not assigning the Vue instance to a variable. I've found out it is unnecessary if you are not actually using the instance variable anywhere after it's initialization.

Comment: Ah, seems like your curiosity was sparked by https://stackoverflow.com/a/59479286/1048572

Comment: That's true @Bergi, I faintly recalled having heard about Vue instances being accessible in `window` scope that way... However, now I'm unable to find a proper reference to this information, so I'll let you figure out an answer to this question and preferably with some reference link :)

Comment: It's `domElement.__vue__` . Underscored name suggests that it's internal, therefore it's suitable for debugging and not production. I'm not sure if it will be available in Vue 3.

Comment: Another hint: Vue Developer Tools needs to be able to somehow detect and access Vue instances, and it should be able to do so even the instance was not bound to a variable.

Comment: The hints you're giving seem to imply that you're looking for a specific answer that you already know (based on [your answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59479286/6277151)). Why the suspense?

Comment: @tony19 that specific way seems to work, as elaborated in that another question's answer, and I faintly recalled hearing about in some educational video etc years ago. However after some time searching I didn't come about any reference as to why / how $vm0, $vm1 etc works. Also there could be other ways. Vue's documentation is lacking in this regard even it seems a valid use case.

Comment: @ux.engineer So now that its several years on, will you comment and share the hints/answers you held back and were 'letting everyone figure out' :)